# Is not accessible in current context

Tags: java, android, generics, scope, android-context

I have the following code

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter<T, V extends BaseAdapter.ViewHolder> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    public BaseAdapter(Context context, int resource, Collection<T> collection) {
        // typical constructor logic
    }

    // some other custom defined methods

    public static class ViewHolder {
        // custom defined logic
    }
}

public class ModelAdapter extends BaseAdapter<Model, ModelAdapter.ModelViewHolder> {
    public ModelAdapter(Context context, int resource, Collection<Model> collection) {
       super(context, resource, collection);
       // typical constructor logic
    }

    public static class ModelViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        // custom defined logic
    }
}
```

The BaseAdapter and ModelAdapter are in separated files. The problem is that I have a compilation error when trying to define the ModelAdapter:
**ModelViewHolder is not accessible in current context**

I don't really understand this error and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Can somebody explain to me this problem or a link that may clarify this situation?

Comment: Can you post the complete compiler message?

Comment: That is the complete compiler message

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Creation Dead Lock**

You use `ModelAdapter.ModelViewHolder` as the template parameter of `BaseAdapter`, and let `ModelAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter`, then the compiler tried to create `ModelViewHolder` first, but the class of `ModelAdapter.ModelViewHolder`(the type is **Class**) is not yet created. It must wait for `ModelAdapter` to be created, because `ModelViewHolder` is in the scope of `ModelAdapter`.

The way to solve it is put the `ModelViewHolder` class into a new *.java file.

Comment: Good answer!  I was totally perplexed by this one.

Comment: I had same task. Probably, it would be more convenient to move ViewHolder class to separate *.java file.

Comment: I still dont understand this... Isnt supposed making the ModelViewHolder static solve this? Static modifier is supposed to make possible for that class to initialize without initializing the parent class...

Answer (score 4):

Here's how it got resolved for me. Generally there shouldn't be a circular dependency problem, as the nested viewholder classes are static. E.g. look at the notorious `LayoutParams` hierarchy, which is built exactly the same way: a class inherits another class and then their static nested classes have corresponding inheritance relationship.
It looks like the circularity comes rather from the visibility scope issue. `ModelViewHolder` may extend `ViewHolder` only as it gets to know it after the outer `ModelAdapter` inherits `BaseAdapter`'s visibility scope. Meanwhile `ModelAdapter` cannot inherit `BaseAdapter` until `ModelViewHolder` class is initialised as it needs for the generic parameter. On the other hand, `ModelViewHolder` is a static nested class and doesn't technically depend on its outer class.
Thus, the solution is to fully qualify the `ViewHolder`'s name when declaring `ModelViewHolder`. Note the `extends BaseAdapter.ViewHolder` part in the snippet below. This way, `ModelViewHolder` doesn't need to use  `ModelAdapter`'s scope to know about `ViewHolder`.

**ModelAdapter.java**

```
public class ModelAdapter extends BaseAdapter<Model, ModelAdapter.ModelViewHolder> {
    public ModelAdapter(Context context, int resource, Collection<Model> collection) {
        super(context, resource, collection);
        // typical constructor logic
    }

    public static class ModelViewHolder extends BaseAdapter.ViewHolder {
        // custom defined logic
    }
}
```

*A note about Android Studio:* Even though the issue itself isn't related to Android Studio, I ran into it by using AS's "Copy class" feature (using AS 3.0). While copying, it "simplified" the code for me, removing the fully qualified name. So, watch out for AS's smartness!

Answer (score 2):

Happened the same to me when extending a Base class. But this time I had it like this (following the given example in the question)

***BaseAdapter.java***

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter<T, V extends BaseAdapter.ViewHolder> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    public BaseAdapter(Context context, int resource, Collection<T> collection) {
        // typical constructor logic
    }

    // some other custom defined methods

    public static class ViewHolder {
        // custom defined logic
    }
}
```

***ModelAdapter.java***

```
import com.mypackage.ModelAdapter.ModelViewHolder; ***//NOTE THIS IMPORT!!!***

public class ModelAdapter extends BaseAdapter<Model, ModelAdapter.ModelViewHolder> {
    public ModelAdapter(Context context, int resource, Collection<Model> collection) {
       super(context, resource, collection);
       // typical constructor logic
    }

    public static class ModelViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        // custom defined logic
    }
}
```

That way the warning was gone and didnt need to separate ModelViewHolder into another '.java' file. Notice that they are in two different files and the **import** in ModelAdapter.java.

I think Fei Liang's answer is partially incorrect because being ModelViewHolder static should make possible to initialize ModelViewHolder without initializing its parent class ModelAdapter

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 1.5.2 and this isn't working for me. Android Studio says the import is unused and still gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before, I'm not sure why that happened, but I resolved it by making the *not-accessible inner* class a *stand-alone class* (not inner means in a separate file).