# Inheritance in interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have two interfaces:

```
public interface EventListener {

    <T extends Data> T modify(T data);

    public static class Data {

    }
}
```

And:

```
public interface ServerInfoEventListener extends EventListener {

    // This works
    @Override ServerInfoData modify(Data data);

    // This doesn't work!
    @Override ServerInfoData modify(ServerInfoData data);

    public static class ServerInfoData extends Data {
        public ServerInfoData(String motd, int playerCount, int maxPlayers) {
            this.motd = motd;
            this.playerCount = playerCount;
            this.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
        }
        public String motd;
        public int playerCount;
        public int maxPlayers;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the comments, `modify(ServerInfoData data)` does not compile. Why not, and how do I fix it? `ServerInfoData` extends `Data`, so it should work, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override ServerInfoData modify(ServerInfoData data)
```

does not work because it does not actually override the `EventListener.modify` since it will not accept any other subclass of `Data` other than `ServerInfoData`  (and *its* subclasses).

You either have to handle *all* `Data` types or make the interface itself generic, not only one method:

```
public interface EventListener<T extends Data> {
    T modify(T data);
}

public interface ServerInfoEventListener extends EventListener<ServerInfoData> {
    @Override ServerInfoData modify(ServerInfoData data);
}
```

Comment: Importantly, if you do this then `Data` cannot exist within `EventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot narrowing down the generic type when override super method.

```
<T extends Data> T modify(T data);
```

This method from interface accepts `Data` and any subclass of `Data`.

But when you override it like:

```
@Override 
ServerInfoData modify(ServerInfoData data);
```

Then your method cannot sibling class of `ServerInfoData` which extends `Data` class, hence it breaks the overridden contract.

Answer (score 1):

I can't adequately explain the specific technical reason why it won't work, but I can explain the fix.

Your interface should use generics at the class-level, not the method-level. We're also required to move `Data` out of `EventListener` (due to [creation deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200301/is-not-accessible-in-current-context)) :

```
class Data
{
    //...
}

interface EventListener<T extends Data>
{
    T modify(T data);
}

interface ServerInfoEventListener extends EventListener<ServerInfoEventListener.ServerInfoData>
{
    @Override ServerInfoData modify(ServerInfoData data);

    class ServerInfoData extends Data {
        //...
    }
}

class ServerInfoEventListenerImpl implements ServerInfoEventListener
{
    @Override
    public ServerInfoData modify(final ServerInfoData data)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As declared in the interface `EventListener` method `modify` requires argument of type `Data` (or any subclass)

`ServerInfoData modify(ServerInfoData data);` takes argument of type `ServerInfoData`, however definiton in interface says "It should take anything, that happens to have superclass of type `Data`" which means that type of arguments of method in subclass does not match what is declared in interface.

Consider this example:

```
public static class AnotherData extends Data {
    // Whatever
}

public void main() {
    EventListener el = new ServerInfoEventListener() {...};
    el.modify(new AnotherData()); // We have a problem
}
```

The problem: There is no method implementation to handle `AnotherData`, but there is supposed to be, because `EventListener` says so. `ServerInfoData modify(ServerInfoData data)` Can't take it, because `AnotherData` is not instanceof `ServerInfoData`

Hope this helps.